# How can I be notified when a NSComboBox selection changes IF the combo box is dynamically added with a new table row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTableView and each row has a NSComboBox. 
[image]

The table column is bounded to NSArrayControllerA and each NSComboBox is bounded to NSArrayControllerB.

I would like to be notified when the selected value in any NSComboBox changes.

So far, I've tried to add a listener to the NSArray managed by the NSArrayControllerB, but I'm not notified about any change.

I've also tried to add an observer to the NSTableView, with a NSComboBoxSelectionDidChangeNotification but it seems the notifications are not propagated to the parent views. And the combo boxes are dynamically created when a new row is inserted.

thanks

**UPDATE**: How is the NSComboBox bound ?

[image]

Comment: Cell- or view-based NSTableView?

Comment: @Conrad Shultz I guess they are view-based (the default one). How can I check ?

Comment: I think cell-based is still the default, actually.  Assuming you are using IB for the UI, check the Content Mode attribute in the Identity Inspector for the table view (be careful that you have the table view selected, not its enclosing scroll view).

Comment: @Conrad Shultz I can't find the content mode attribute. THis is a screenshot of my identity Inspector: http://cl.ly/Dl51

Comment: Ah, Xcode 3.  I gather that you are on Snow Leopard?  If so, then cell-based is the only option.

Comment: @Conrad Shultz I'm on Lion but I'm developing apps which must be compatible with Leopard as well. It is probably cell-based.

Comment: @Conrad Shultz ... you also have the solution to the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I just awoke (I'm on the US west coast).  Do you actually want to know when the selection changes via the UI, or are you (more likely) concerned when the model changes?

Comment: no worries.. both of them are fine but please read my attemps in my question. ive tried few things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>OK. I assume you've bound the combo box's selection to the array controller's selection? If so, try observing the array controller's selectionIndex property. (It's KVO-compliant.)</strike>

On my iPhone so I can't easily test right now, but that should do the trick.

OK, scratch that, now that I better understand the question.

How about instead you set the selector for the cell to some method in your controller (with an outlet to the enclosing table view), say, -comboBoxClicked: and then implement something like:

```
- (void)comboBoxClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger changedRow = [[self tableView] selectedRow];
    // Do something with changedRow
}
```

I did a cursory test (just NSLogging changedRow) and it seemed to work for me, at least in a very basic application.

Comment: Oh, wait, I might have misunderstood your question. Is each combo box bound to the SAME array controller?  I assumed not (since you tried listening for changes to NSArrayControllerB's array), but if they are, obviously you wouldn't bind the selection as well, so this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: Ya, each NSComboBox is binded to the same array controller and precisely to the arranged objects (not the selection), because I use it to populate the combo box list. Then, the table column (containing the combo boxes) is binded to another array controller (arrangedObjects as well), that I use to get the content of the table when I need it.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing. I've been sick for few days. I've done what you suggest and it works. I still need a last tip: when the IBAction is triggered, the new value is already updated in the tableView arrayController and it seems there is no way to know which one was the older value from the code.

Comment: Yeah, that's how bindings work.  Can you just observe arrayControllerA's representedObjects?  I'm not entirely clear on your architecture, but if it behaves as I think it does then you should be able to accomplish what you want by using NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld.

Comment: Did you mean arrangedObjects ? I can't find representedObjects as member of a NSArrayController

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I've been writing a lot of NSViewController code recently.  I meant arrangedObjects.  If an object is inserted/removed/replaced, it should trigger a KVO notification on arrangedObjects.

Comment: In the end I've solved by saving the current displayed objects in an additional array, and getting the old names from such array. The problem with the notification was that it was triggered *after* comboBoxClicked, so I couldn't get the old value from the method. With the array of old values it works fine.. thanks for help...

Comment: Glad that you got it working. But did you specify NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld when setting up your observer? That will cause the old value to be included in the observation notification, eliminating the need to record the old value yourself.

Comment: Ya, I've specified it. But the problem was that the notification was delivered after comboBoxClicked triggering.